# I am creating a role for DDL deployments in snowflake, would like to avoid accountadmin

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Which privileges should be granted to this role, I am getting insufficient privileges when running

```
ALTER ACCOUNT SET TIMESTAMP_TYPE_MAPPING = 'TIMESTAMP_LTZ',TIMEZONE = 'UTC';
```

OR is there an alternate method/query to achieve this without having to use the accountadmin role.

Answer (score 0):

[ALTER ACCOUNT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-account):

> Account administrators (i.e. **users with the ACCOUNTADMIN role**) to set and unset:
>
> - **Account parameters, which cannot be changed by any other users.**

---

[Parameter Management](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-management)

> Snowflake provides three types of parameters that can be set for your account:
>
> - Account parameters that affect your entire account.
> - Session parameters that default to users and their sessions.
> - Object parameters that default to objects (warehouses, databases, schemas, and tables).
>
> All parameters have default values, which can be overridden at the account level. **To override default values at the account level, you must be an account administrator (i.e. user granted the ACCOUNTADMIN role).**

Comment: Yes unfortunately even I could find anything for parameter setting, it is not granular in snowflake.